# Function to get HTML syntax coloring in R

Tags: r, syntax, knitr

I was wondering if there is a way to have HTML output with syntax coloring of a line of code in R. It should do something like:

```
HTMLoutput <- HTMLsysntaxColoring("a <- paste('hello,', 'world')")
```

The output should be readable HTML code that shows the line with R syntax coloring.
Knit does something like this for a whole document, but I would like to have it for a single command line.

The reason why I am doing this is that I am developing a package to do profiling in R (it is in CRAN, GUIProfiler). It builds an HTML report that includes the profiled code shadowed for the places that take more time. Unfortunately, I used Nozzle.R1 instead of knitr to generate the report. Nozzle.R1 seems to be discontinued and is not able to display the code with syntax coloring. knitr is actively updated and does have syntax coloring.

Instead of rebuild the package from scratch using knitr (perhaps is what I will do in the future), I was trying "to patch it" using knitr to generate the syntax coloring and pasting it into the Nozzle.R1 package.

Comment: It really isn't clear to me what you're looking for. Can you add some more details to make the desired outcome more clear?

Comment: Can do it for shiny with variations on `tags$style(type='text/css', "#myDiv { height: 200px; }")`,

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it, though I'm curious as to what you're really actually looking for.

````
html_syntax_coloring <- function(r_code) {
  require(knitr)
  r_code <- paste0("```{r eval=FALSE}\n", paste0(r_code, collapse="\n"), "\n```")
  tmp_in <- tempfile(fileext=".Rmd")
  cat(r_code, file=tmp_in)
  tmp_out <- tempfile(fileext=".html")
  on.exit(unlink(tmp_out))
  knit2html(tmp_in, tmp_out, quiet=TRUE)
  paste0(readLines(tmp_out), collapse="\n")
}

html_syntax_coloring("a <- paste('hello,', 'world')")
````